# difference between action and action.async

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I wrote 2 actions to test the difference between action and action.asyc. However, I've found that both of the 2 methods return value after Thread.sleep complete. Should action.asyc return the value immediately as per the description?

```
def intensiveComputation(): Int = {
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    return 1
}

def testPromise() = Action {
   Ok("sync" + intensiveComputation())
}

def testPromise = Action.async {
   val futureint = scala.concurrent.Future { intensiveComputation() }
   futureint.map(i => Ok("async" + i))
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you have observed, as an end-user (i.e. in the browser), there will be no apparent difference between your two code snippets.

The difference is that with your `"sync"` case, the entire thread/actor/whatever-it-is that handles your request in Play has been tied up, twiddling its thumbs while it waits for `Thread.sleep` to finish.

In the `"async"` case by contrast, the handling function *has actually run* and thus the resource that ran it (the thread/actor/whatever) is freed up to do other things. When the `Future` eventually completes, it can finish off the job.

The best way to see the difference is to sprinkle in a couple of log entries:

```
def intensiveComputation(): Int = {
  Logger.info("Sleeping")
  Thread.sleep(5000)
  Logger.info("Woke up")
  return 1
}

def testPromiseSync() = Action {
  val result = Ok("sync" + intensiveComputation())
  Logger.info("returning to Play")
  result
}

def testPromiseAsync = Action.async {
  val futureint = scala.concurrent.Future { intensiveComputation() }
  val f = futureint.map(i => Ok("async" + i))
  Logger.info("returning to Play")
  f
}
```

When we hit the `sync` endpoint, we see:

```
2014-05-14 17:23:39,359 [info] application - Sleeping
2014-05-14 17:23:44,359 [info] application - Woke up
2014-05-14 17:23:44,359 [info] application - returning to Play
```

And the `async`:

```
2014-05-14 17:24:23,376 [info] application - Sleeping
2014-05-14 17:24:23,376 [info] application - returning to Play
2014-05-14 17:24:28,376 [info] application - Woke up
```

So by employing `Action.async` you freed up Play to handle more requests "at once", while keeping the end-user experience unchanged.

Comment: You are too fast. Good answer.

Comment: The "... **the entire thread/actor/whatever-it-is that handles your request in Play has been tied up**, twiddling its thumbs while it waits for Thread.sleep to finish.." statement seems a bit confusing to me. Since Actions in Play are async by default and thread **handling** the request is not blocked.